# Calculating moments of a binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

I have the following problem:

If $X$ satisfies a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, its expected value is $np$ and variance is $np(1-p)$. Prove these using formulas given in pages 8 and 10.

On page 8 we have been given that

$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^k P(X=x_i)x_i$,

$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2=\sum_{i=1}^kp_i(x_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i=1}^kP(X=x_i)(x_i-\mu)^2$

and on page 10 we have formulas for $E(a+bX), \operatorname{Var}(a+bX), E(X+Y), \operatorname{Var}(X\pm Y)$.

I already managed to find a proof using the identity $x^2\binom{n}{x}=xn\binom{n-1}{x-1}$ which does not use the formulas above but as we haven't given that identity in the course, I was wondering whether there is an alternative proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you happen to know ProofWiki?
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Binomial_Distribution

This might be helpful for further work.

Comment: Ah. I think it's the proof 2 in that web site the professor wants. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
E(X) &= \sum x P(x)\\
&= \sum x .C^n_x.p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
&= \sum x .\dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}.p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
&= \sum \dfrac{n!}{(x-1)!(n-x)!}.p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
&= np\sum \dfrac{(n-1)!}{(x-1)!(n-x)!}.p^{x-1}(1-p)^{(n-1)-(x-1)} \\
&= np\sum C^{n-1}_{x-1}.p^{x-1}(1-p)^{(n-1)-(x-1)} \\
&= np\times 1\\
&= np
\end{align}